# gSoap QT undefined reference

Tags: c++, qt, soap, gsoap

i'm trying to use gSOAP to create a c++/QT server/client

this is my Test.h file

```
//gsoap ns service name:    ColisageMutexService
//gsoap ns service style:   rpc
//gsoap ns service encoding:    literal
//gsoap ns service location:    http://localhost:1444
//gsoap ns schema namespace: urn:ColisageMutex
class FamilleProduit
{
private:
    int Id;
    std::string Libelle;
public:
    FamilleProduit();
    ~FamilleProduit();
    int getId();
    void setId(int value);
    std::string getLibelle();
    void setLibelle(std::string value);
};

//gsoap ns service method-action: ajouterByType ""

int ns__ajouterByType ( FamilleProduit familleproduit, bool * result);

//gsoap ns service method-action: ajouterByLibelle ""

int ns__ajouterByLibelle ( std::string libelle, bool * result);
```

I run  `oapcpp2.exe -I -pTest Test.h` and I integrate the generated code with my project but the probleme that the compiler keep giving me errors

```
error: undefined reference to `ns__ajouterByType(soap*, FamilleProduit, bool*)
```

and

```
error: undefined reference to `ns__ajouterByLibelle(soap*, std::string, bool*)
```

even that i added in my main the implement of this tow function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the probleme was in the implementation of the methods I forget to put

```
struct soap* soap
```

in the definition of the methods